# How can I validate dsym file of xcode build?

Tags: xcode, undefined-symbol, crittercism, dsym

I extract Dsym file from the xarchive of release version and uploaded on crittercism but not able to find the symbolic crash report from the tool.

I contact crittercism helpDesk and all I come to know that I need to upload dsym file with all symbols... so, how can I validate that the file which I'm uploading is valid or not?

Build setting : GCC_GENERATE_DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS : Yes

File extract step :  organizer > xarchive > release build > show package contents > dsyms > dsym.file

Answer (score 1):

Apteligent also provides an automatic way using which, you'll never have to worry about tracking down your dSYMs again. This can be achieved by uploading the build_script file which is available inside the Apteligent iOS library (v4.0.1 and higher). All you need to do is specify the APP ID, API Key and the source path in order to configure your Xcode. Refer to the following article for complete description :

http://support.crittercism.com/articles/knowledge_base/Uploading-dSYMs-to-Apteligent-automatically

Once done, whenever you build your Xcode application, the dSYM files for your application (and any dependent modules to which you added the Run Script) will be uploaded to Apteligent and become available for crash symbolication.